# Remove indentation from an ordered list within a webview

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, webview

I am creating an ordered list within a webview and I want to remove the indentation from the list, i.e. have the list aligned with the first paragraph. Here's HTML:

```
<body  style="font-family: arial""font-size:18">
 <p>First paragraph.</p>
 <p>
  <ol style="margin-left:0px">
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
  </ol>
 </p>
</body>
```

Notice that with the `margin-left:0px`, the webview still indents the list by about 17 points. If I say `margin-left:-17px`, I can make it work with a hack but would rather not as it seems more like I'm doing something wrong with the construction of my HTML.

Can anyone see any problems with it?

**Updated HTML - Still doesn't work:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    ol {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Paragraph.</p>
    <p>
    <ol>
        <li>List item 1.</li>
        <li>List item 2.</li>
        <li>List item 3.</li>
    </ol>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using iOS 5.1 on iPhone 3GS

Comment: a `<ol>` can never be wrapped in a `<p>`

Comment: ol MOST Definitely can be wrapped in <p>! <p> tags are simply <divs> by another name with a little styling. Anyway I got it to work... se my answer below.

Comment: Yeah I solved it... see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You can archive style like that with :

```
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as above "When I do that, I need to give padding a value so that the list is not shifted off the left-hand side of the screen. Still feels a bit hacky. Did you do this on iOS?"

Answer (score 2):

Try This....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    .flush-left {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
</style>    
</head>
<body>
    <p>First paragraph.</p>
    <p>
        <ol class="flush-left">
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
        </ol>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

A couple of other pointers. Test your stuff out in test files in html on your desktop and load them into Safari and the iOS Simulator (Drag html file onto safari open in simulator).

But then you can use Regular Safari Debug tools to examine the html and css. or Firebug in Firefox.

Also, when in doubt www.w3schools.com ... :)

Comment: Thanks for this. When I do that, I need to give padding a value so that the list is not shifted off the left-hand side of the screen. Still feels a bit hacky. Did you do this on iOS?

Comment: Yes I did it in iOS. I copy your HTML above. Save to file on desktop. change your style on <ol> tag to what I wrote above and open in iPhone 5.1 Simulator I get exactly what you asked for. A list with padding removed, and flush left with para. This is not hacky this is standard css. If your shifted off left hand side then it is because you still have that negative margin you mentioned you tried somewhere on the page. Also, I recommend you use styles in a head section.

Comment: Strange. The code is literally what I gave you, so I haven't a stray 'margin' anywhere. I'll try it in the simulator a little later to see if there's a difference.

Comment: In you original post up top you said you added "margin-left:-17px" somewhere. If that is still there or where ever you put it, then that is what would cause it to go off the left of the page.. your missing something in your html.

Comment: Also see another typo in the style on your body tag. You posted: style="font-family: arial""font-size:18" (not double quotes between arial and font. That should probably read style="font-family: arial";font-size:18"

Comment: Yes, I simply replaced 'margin' with 'padding'. I was trying to say that there is nothing more to the file than that.

Comment: Well... i have no idea what your problem is then because when I copy either of the code blocks I pasted above into a text file and pull into my iOS Simulator it works perfect. Your missing something. Just paste it all again here... and we will see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15539/discussion-between-remover-and-cliff-ribaudo)

Comment: Ok Im over in the chat you set up

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm a bit late for your needs – I just came across this.

I only noticed this on my iPhone, and not my iPad, nor Safari on the Mac. I found that a bit strange that this issue would only be in the one version of Safari, and not all. I wasn't happening in Chrome either.

When looking in the Chrome developer tools, I noticed that the user agent stylesheet had added a number of -webkit prefixed styles, all to do with margin and padding:

```
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
-webkit-padding-start: 40px;
```

When I first saw that, I was wondering if that was the issue, but, it was late, and I had to take a sleep break. Today, I tackled it again, but forgot about these styles. I looked around, and came across @Remover's question. But, setting a specific pixel-based margin or padding didn't sit well with me.

At some point, I decided to narrow my browser window in Chrome, and low and behold the issue was there as well, only when I narrowed it to be close to the width of an iPhone. So, this isn't just an iOS issue. It's webkit.

I looked again at the styles in the dev tools, and saw again the -webkit styles, and the 40px on -webkit-padding-start. I played around with my css, and that was indeed the culprit.

I then added the following to my stylesheet:

```
ol {
    -webkit-padding-start: 2em;
    -ms-padding-start: 2em;
    -moz-padding-start: 2em;
    -o-padding-start: 2em;
    padding-start: 2em;
}
```

I did some quick research, and it looks like only -webkit and -moz are using padding-start, but I added the rest, just in case they pick it up – though, now that Opera has switched to webkit, -o probably isn't needed.

In my case, I used 2em, as that worked with my style. Not sure if 2em will work across the board or not.

**Edit**

I should have also mentioned that it probably only shows up on small screens because it's set at 40px. In my design, my base font-size at full screen is 23px, and at 480px and below is 10px, which is quite a bit of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you merely assign a padding of zero, the bullets go off the screen. I found that the following worked perfectly for my webview

```
ul,ol {padding-left: 20px;}
li {padding-left:2px;}
```

Answer (score -2):

isn't it

```
 <ul><li></li></ul>
```

not `<ol>` ?

also it looks the you might have a syntax error on your style for your body tag

:)

~ Dan

Comment: ul = unordered list, bullets. ol = ordered list, numbered.